# Deleting all products in Magento store

Tags: magento-1.9, delete

For Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Never used PHP before, the website I'm working with wants all products deleted. There are about 6000. I believe you make a php file with the code that deletes the products, through ftp? Then, run the example example.com/delete.php and it should work?

Sorry for the beginner question. What is the code for deleting all products and making sure the images are removed from the server as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all products via the Magento admin. Just go to Catalog > Products and select "Select All". Now all products are selected and you can remove them by changing the action's selectbox option on the right and set it to "Delete". Now click the button next to it and wait.

Comment: Maximum display count here is 200. So if there is 5000 it would take him 25 times to delete everything using the way you described. So, your answer is not completely correct. Some file PHP job is in order, as @CFlynn said.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but there's a difference between "Select All" and "Select All Visible". The last one is indeed related to the number of visible products, which is at a max of 200 per page. "Select All" however will delete all products. It is pretty slow though.

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for mass delete of a large product database I suggest using SQL to achieve it:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_enabled_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;

TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;

INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_type`(`link_type_id`,`code`) VALUES (1,'relation'),(2,'bundle'),(3,'super'),(4,'up_sell'),(5,'cross_sell');
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute`(`product_link_attribute_id`,`link_type_id`,`product_link_attribute_code`,`data_type`) VALUES (1,2,'qty','decimal'),(2,1,'position','int'),(3,4,'position','int'),(4,5,'position','int'),(6,1,'qty','decimal'),(7,3,'position','int'),(8,3,'qty','decimal');
INSERT  INTO `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`stock_name`) VALUES (1,'Default');
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

This was previously suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899366/deleting-all-products-on-magento